# Magento translations ok in online program but not run as cronjob

Tags: magento, module, cron, translation

I created a module (extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract) and an admin controller.

When I run this module online translations are going right.

When I run this module as cronjob, everything goes allright but translations are not done, I specified translation file in config.xml in as well frontend as adminhtml.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: I think this is a bug, difficult to debug a cron job. I have not find cronjobs with translations used. So meanwhile I fixed this by defining my own public function __() in my own _Helper_Data class. I retrieve $locale = Mage::app()->getLocale()->getLocaleCode(); and do my own translations hard in this function ..

Comment: This was for release 1.5, maybe this works in next releases ..

Answer (score 3):

I see this is a very old question. I've posted here to future reference and others.

---

**Quick and dirty solution**

```
// Fix unitialized translator
Mage::app()->getTranslator()->init('frontend', true);
```

just after

```
$initialEnvironmentInfo = $appEmulation>startEnvironmentEmulation($storeId);
```

for instance. Or in a `foreach` loop of your own, which is called via cron/admin. Since you're talking about crons, I assume that you know what you are doing.

**The real problem**

In Magento 1.9 in `Mage_Core_Model_App_Emulation` (in `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App/Emulation.php`), there's this function:

```
/**
 * Apply locale of the specified store
 *
 * @param integer $storeId
 * @param string $area
 *
 * @return string initial locale code
 */
protected function _emulateLocale($storeId, $area = Mage_Core_Model_App_Area::AREA_FRONTEND)
{
    $initialLocaleCode = $this->_app->getLocale()->getLocaleCode();
    $newLocaleCode = $this->_getStoreConfig(Mage_Core_Model_Locale::XML_PATH_DEFAULT_LOCALE, $storeId);
    if ($initialLocaleCode != $newLocaleCode) {
        $this->_app->getLocale()->setLocaleCode($newLocaleCode);
        $this->_factory->getSingleton('core/translate')->setLocale($newLocaleCode)->init($area, true);
    }
    return $initialLocaleCode;
}
```

The `$initialLocaleCode != $newLocaleCode` seems to be the issue here. When iteration orders/customers/subscribers/*, the locale could stay the same, which then prevents executing the code in the statement. And the locale is thus not set in the Translator (`Mage::app()->getTranslator()`).

We've yet to fix the issue, but you could change `if ($initialLocaleCode != $newLocaleCode) {` to `if (true) {` straight in the core source. Off course, this is ugly. I suggest something like extending the class and then :

```
/**
 * Apply locale of the specified store. Extended
 * to fix Magento's uninitialized translator.
 *
 * @see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19940733/magento-translations-ok-in-online-program-but-not-run-as-cronjob#
 * @param integer $storeId
 * @param string $area
 *
 * @return string initial locale code
 */
protected function _emulateLocale($storeId, $area = Mage_Core_Model_App_Area::AREA_FRONTEND)
{
    $initialLocaleCode = $this->_app->getLocale()->getLocaleCode();
    $newLocaleCode = $this->_getStoreConfig(Mage_Core_Model_Locale::XML_PATH_DEFAULT_LOCALE, $storeId);

    $this->_app
        ->getLocale()
        ->setLocaleCode($newLocaleCode);

    $this->_factory
        ->getSingleton('core/translate')
        ->setLocale($newLocaleCode)
        ->init($area, true);

    return $initialLocaleCode;
}
```

**Magento 2**

I guess the developers became aware it was borked and they changed the code in Magento 2. The `_emulateLocale()` function is gone all together and they added this line to the `startEnvironmentEmulation()` function, without any conditional around it:

```
$this->_localeResolver->setLocale($newLocaleCode);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug even with `CE 1.9.0.1`!

See what I've done about it:

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/25612/cron-job-template-block-not-being-translated-but-testobserver-is/25920#25920